# How to make sure a set of points are not chosen again by rand()

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm writing a code that performs a random scan over a set of 4 numbers. I'd like to scan 10000 points (millions later). I just learned about rand(), so here's the relevant part:

```
int numPoints = 10000;
double A,B,C,D;
 for (i=0; i<=numPoints1;i++) {

                srand ( time(NULL) );
                A = rand() % 500 + 100;
                B = rand() % 500 + 100;
                C = rand() % 100 - 100;        
                D = rand() % 5 + 2.5;
```

Then these four variable are fed into a function (A,B,C,D).
The code performs some checks and calculations inside the loop.

```
 }
```

However, I noticed in the output file that many times, the same set of A,B,C,D is picked.

**Q:** Any suggestions as to how can I improve the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the call to `srand` out of the loop. Like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <= numPoints1; i++)
{
   ...
}
```

What's happening is that you're re-initializing the random number generator with each iteration. As I recall, `time` returns the time as a number of seconds. So `time(NULL)` will only change once per second, meaning that you'll be seeding the random number with the same seed multiple times.

That said, this won't guarantee that a set of numbers isn't repeated. It will, however, make duplicates much less likely.